# Set permissions while writing files to Box.com from R

Tags: r, ftp

My first posted question ever--I try to be self-sufficient!

I write files to a folder on Box.com that I share selectively with individuals in our company. I do this directly from within R, which makes the process remarkably easy--except for setting access permissions for the folder or files. I use code like the following to write the files to Box via FTP:

```
ftpUpload(what = "MyLocalFile.xml",
        to = "ftp.box.com:21/MyFolder/MyFileOnBox.xml",
        verbose = TRUE,
        userpwd = "MySecretIdentity@MySecretCompany:Don'tStealMyPassword!", 
        ftp.use.epsv = FALSE)
```

Does anyone know how to set permissions for the files (or the folder) automatically via the ftp command? Or some other function within R that could do so?

Sincere thanks,
BugHunter

Comment: You might be able to use the RCurl option that corresponds to `CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS` (search  for details on http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) assuming that you're using sftp.

Comment: Thanks Hadley!  I'll check that route out.

Comment: Unfortunately, Box Support says this functionality is not available.

Comment: try their http api: http://developers.box.com/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

Although this might be an old question and you might have already fixed, I will add here a solution that could help anyone coming across this topic.

There are some extra arguments that you can pass to `RCurl::ftpUpload` and can help you in pre and post load tasks:

```
ftpUpload(what = "MyLocalFile.xml",
          to = "ftp.box.com:21/MyFolder/MyFileOnBox.xml",
          verbose = TRUE,
          userpwd = "MySecretIdentity@MySecretCompany:Don'tStealMyPassword!",
          prequote = c('mkdir MyFolder', 'chgrp gid MyFolder'),
          postquote = c('chmod 770 /MyFolder/MyFileOnBox.xml', 
                        'chgrp gid /MyFolder/MyFileOnBox.xml'),
          ftp.use.epsv = FALSE)
```

Example above is on assumption you are uploading to a Unix-like OS.

Hope this can help anyone coming across the same issue.